# Add a class iteratively with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I'm creating a grid 16x16 with javascript. I also want the grid to do something when the mouse hover over each square. The problem is that I do not know how to add a class in a iterative way that every div get the same class.

Doing so, I would make jQuery do the action with one function applied to that class.

This is my present code

```
var contador = 1;
var outra = document.createElement('div');
outra.id = 'container';
document.body.appendChild(outra);

for (i=1;i<=16;i++){
  for (j=1;j<=16;j++){
    var divCreation = document.createElement('div');
    var created = divCreation;
    created.id = "numero"+ contador;
    console.log(created.id); 
    created.textContent = ". ";
    contador = contador + 1;
    outra.appendChild(created);
  }
}

$('#numero'+contador).hover(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just add it during creation with `created.className = "whatever"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give a specific `class` to your dynamically created elements, you can do it using **[`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)** property.

Your code would be like this:

```
divCreation.className = "someClass";
```

**Note:**

- I don't see why you are setting `divCreation` in a new variable, it's
  just useless.
- And instead of detecting `hover` with jQuery, you can just do it with css, look at my Demo below, or if you want to keep jquery you can use the class selector like this `$('.box').hover(...)`.

**Demo:**

```js
var outra = document.createElement('div');
outra.id = 'container';
var contador = 1;
document.body.appendChild(outra);

for (i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= 16; j++) {
    var created = document.createElement('div');
    created.className = "box";
    created.id = "numero" + contador;
    created.textContent = ". ";
    contador++;
    outra.appendChild(created);
  }
}
```

```css
.box:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`attribute starts with`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```
$('[id^=numero').hover(
```

or provide a class to the element and target the elements using the class

This will select all the elements whose `id` starts with the value you are specifying and attach a `hover` event.

And when you are using `jQuery`, why do you want to mix in both Vanilla JS and jQuery. You can just stick with one.

```js
var contador = 1;
var $outra = $('<div/>', {
   id: 'container',
   class: 'container'
});

$('body').append($outra);

for (i=1;i<=16;i++){
  for (j=1;j<=16;j++) {
    var $divCreation = $('<div/>', {
     id: 'numero' + contador,
      text: '. ',
      class: 'box'
    });
   
    $outra.append($divCreation);
    contador = contador + 1;
  }
}

$('[id^=numero').hover(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The use of the attribute starts with selector is likely to be less swift than simply selecting by class.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The likely question on performance is secondary. I feel the answer is more in lieu of how the Op can solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

No need for use of ID for this at all...just use a common class. Also since using jQuery can create all this with a lot less code using by using it.

```js
var $outra = $('<div>', { id: 'container'});

for (i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= 16; j++) {
    $outra.append( $('<div>', { class: 'box', text: '.'}) );
  }
}
$('body').append($outra);

$('.box').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('yellow');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}

.box.yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```